# ASP.NET MVC Dropdownlistfor is saving gender_id in place of gender_type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created controller and views from entity framework, I have modified one of my textboxes into dropdownlist and dropdownlist data is coming from a table named tbl_gender. Now when I save the data, gender_id is saved in place of gender_type.

My create.cshtml is-

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Gender", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.author_gender, ViewBag.genderList as SelectList, "--select gender--", new  { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.author_gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller is-

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "author_id,author_name,author_DOB,author_gender,author_mobile,author_email,author_image,author_create_date,author_created_by")] tbl_author tbl_author)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var getGender = db.tbl_gender.ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(getGender, "gender_id", "gender_type", tbl_author.author_gender);
        ViewBag.genderList = list;
        db.tbl_author.Add(tbl_author);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(tbl_author);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB760.png)

it is saving `gender_id` instead of `gender_type`

Comment: Because the 2nd parameter of of the `SelectList` specifies the option values. but it should be saving the ID of the related table anyway.

Comment: Then how can I save the gender_type only?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that - you have a table with a FK relationship - it should be storing the `gender_id`

Comment: I don't have the FK relationship with the table tbl_gender

Comment: Then why not - you have a table to store the genders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID value of the SelectList is set as the value of the options in the HTML select which is rendered, so it is this value which is passed to your action. If you want to use the gender_type then specify that as the ID when you create the DropdownList e.g.

```
SelectList list = new SelectList(getGender, "gender_type", "gender_type", tbl_author.author_gender);
```

There may be another overload which means you don't have to specify gender_type twice but I can't think off the top of my head.

Comment: Is it not a Correct Method

Comment: No problem. While this will have helped you in the short term you might want to have a think about the comments by Stephen Muecke regarding the foreign key relationship between your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Gender Id is a Primary Key so that is stored as foreign in another table if you want to save gender, type get it that id and find value from the gender table and replace it controller and save to deb. Its First Solution, If you want Store in Id and Display in Type will change details Page Controller to Replace Using ViewModel